# Makefile: capture error code in rule, ignore error, take decision based on error code

Tags: shell, makefile

So, I currently have this:

```
TEST = "?"
oktest:
    @-/bin/false && ([ $$? -eq 0 ] && echo "success!") || true; $(eval TEST = "all ok")
    @echo $(TEST)
badtest:
    @-/bin/false && ([ $$? -eq 0 ] && echo "success!") || true; $(eval TEST = "got error")
    @echo $(TEST)
    @T=echo;if [ $(TEST) = "got error" ]; then \
        echo "some error detected, cleanup env and fail test"; \
        /bin/false; \
    fi
all: oktest badtest
```

As you can see, its based on:

- ignoring error codes ("-" and "|| true", both will do, but I prefer this way)
- doing run-time comparison with shell code.
- aborting with shell command returning false.

Is there a way to make it shorter, save returned error code and compare it to known values in runtime - without falling back to embedded shell code or external scripts?

Comment: Neither of those `$(eval ...)` calls are conditional on the shell return code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here exactly. Do you have a more realistic scenario you can show?